# swt/jface databinding: PojoProperties vs PojoObservable

Tags: data-binding, jface, eclipse-databinding

I'm writing a JFace dialog, and I'd like to use databing to a model object.

Looking at code I can see that there are times when I find a `PojoProperties` used to build the binding, while other time it is used a `PojoObservables`.

Looking at the Javadoc I can read:

**PojoObservables**: A factory for creating ***observable objects*** for POJOs (plain old java objects) that conform to idea of an object with getters and setters but does not provide property change events on change.

**PojoProperties**: A factory for creating ***properties*** for POJOs (plain old Java objects) that conform to idea of an object with getters and setters but does not provide property change events on change.

The same question applies to the difference that exists between **BeansObservables** and **BeansProperties**

The (obvious) difference sems to be that the observable allows to observe objects and the properties allows to observe properties, but since a Pojo has a getter and a setter for its data, what is the difference between them? And which of them should I choose for my dialog?

Here follows a code excerpt:

**The POJO:**

```java
public class DataObject {
  private String m_value;
  public String getValue() {
    return m_value;
  }
  public void setValue(String i_value) {
    m_value = i_value;
  }
}
```

**The DIALOG (relevant part):**

```java
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

    m_combo = new Combo(container, SWT.BORDER);
    m_comboViewer = new ComboViewer(container, SWT.NONE);

}
```

**The BINDING (relevant part):**

```java
    // using PojoObservable
    IObservableValue observeValue = PojoObservables.observeValue(m_dataObject, "value");
    IObservableValue observeWidget = SWTObservables.observeSelection(m_combo);

    // using PojoProperties
    IObservableValue observeValue = PojoProperties.value("value").observe(m_dataObject);
    IObservableValue observeWidget = ViewerProperties.singleSelection().observe(m_comboViewer);
```

I understand that one time I'm using a combo and another I'm using a `ComboViewer`, but I can get the combo from the viewer and bind the other way if I need...

Also, can I mix the two, for example use the `observeValue` with the `ViewerProperties`?

```java
    IObservableValue observeValue = PojoObservables.observeValue(m_dataObject, "value");
    IObservableValue observeWidget = ViewerProperties.singleSelection().observe(m_comboViewer);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am playing around a little with JFace viewers (especially ComboViewer) & databinding and discovered that if I use

```
SWTObservables.observeSelection(comboViewer.getCombo());
```

then databinding is not working correctly.

However, if I use

```
ViewersObservables.observeSingleSelection(comboViewer);
```

Then everything is working as expected.

Maybe this is a special for my case, so to get it a better overview I'll describe my set up in following paragraph.

I have `modelObject` with field named `selectedEntity` and `entities` and bind this `ComboViewer` to the `modelObject`.

- I want to display all "entities" in model object, if I add any entity to the `modelObject.entities` collection then I want to this entity be added to combo automatically.
- If user selects some item in combo I want to `modelObject.selectedEntity` be set automatically.
- If I set `modelObject.selectedEntity` I want to combo selection be set automatically.

Source code can be found at: https://gist.github.com/3938502

Answer (score 1):

Since Eclipse Mars, PojoObservables is deprecated in favor of PojoProperties and BeansObservables is deprecated in favor of BeanProperties so the answer to which one should be used has now become evident.